# How to subclass QSqlTableModel in pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

After hanging around with some posts with C++ answers which don't fit to my question and which are more confusing than explaining I try to ask here.
I'm trying to subclass `QSqlTableModel` because I need some boolean columns with checkboxes. The complete working program is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
import sys

class ImportFilter (QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        print("Welcome to StandardDialog")
        # Load the Window
        #self.ui = uic.loadUi("ImportFilter.ui",self)
        #self.ui.setModal(True)
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox()
        self.tableView_typeOfValues = QTableView()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView_typeOfValues)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Init Environmment
        self.db = createConnection()

        # create Models
        self.setupModel()

        #setup Views
        self.setupView()

        # connect Signals
        self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_Box_clicked)

        self.show()
        print("<- initUI")

    def setupView(self):
        print("-> setupView")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setModel(self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(0,10)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(1,130)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(2,130)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(3,60)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(4,60)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(5,60)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.setColumnWidth(6,60)

        self.tableView_typeOfValues.hideColumn(0)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues.hideColumn(3)
        print("<- setupView")

    def setupModel(self):
        print("-> setupModel")
        # own model
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model = ImportSqlTableModel()
        print("   tables:", self.db.tables())
        print('   Before .setTable("typeOfValue") and select()')
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.info()
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setTable("typeOfValue")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.select()
        print('   After .setTable("typeOfValue") and select()')
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.info()
        self.headerData()
        print("   Table:",self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.tableName())
        print("   count:",self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.rowCount())

        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.info()
        print("<- setupModel")

    def setupModelQRY(self):
        print("-> setupModel with Query")
        # works so far
        #self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model = QSqlTableModel()  # edit but no checkboxes
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model = ImportSqlTableModel(self.db) # no edit
        # SET query
        qry = QSqlQuery(self.db)
        sql = "SELECT ID, name, unit, source, Import, ImportIfZero, visible FROM typeOfValue"
        qry.prepare(sql)
        qry.exec_(sql)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setQuery(qry)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.select()
        print("   Filter:",self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.filter())
        print("   SELECT:", self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.selectStatement())
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        print("<- setupModel")

    def headerData(self):
        print("-> headerData")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(0,Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(1,Qt.Horizontal, "name")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(2,Qt.Horizontal, "unit")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(3,Qt.Horizontal, "source")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(4,Qt.Horizontal, "Import")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(5,Qt.Horizontal, "ImportIfZero")
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setHeaderData(6,Qt.Horizontal, "visible")
        print("<- headerData")


    ###################################################################################################
    #                        functions
    ###################################################################################################
    def pushButton_Box_clicked(self,signal):
        print("okButtonClicked")
        print("buttonBox_clicked",signal)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.submitAll()
        self.exitcode = "ok, but not implemented"
        sys.exit()

    def returnCode(self):
        return self.exitcode

#######################################################################################################################
#                                               C L A S S
#######################################################################################################################

class ImportSqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImportSqlTableModel, self).__init__()
        print("-> ImportSqlTableModel.__init__:")
        self.booleanSet =[4,5,6]
        self.readOnlySet = [1]
        print("   Inside:")
        self.info()
        print("<- ImportSqlTableModel.__init__:")


    def info(self):
        print("-> info")

        print("   ImportSqlTableModel tables inside :", self.database().tables())
        print("   ImportSqlTableModel self.db       :", self.database())
        print("   ImportSqlTableModel self.Table    :", self.tableName())
        print("   ImportSqlTableModel self.rowCount :", self.rowCount())
        print("   ImportSqlTableModel self.lastEror :", self.lastError().text())
        print("<- info")
    def columnCount(self, index):
        count = QSqlTableModel.columnCount(self, index)
        return count

    def dataChanged(self, QModelIndex, QModelIndex_1, Iterable, p_int=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print("-> Datachanged")

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        print("-> ImportSqlModel.data",index, role)
        print("   1row   :", index.row())
        print("   col    :", index.column())
        print("   data   :", self.record().fieldName(index.column()))
        value = super(ImportSqlTableModel, self).data(index)
        print("  value2:",value)

        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                if value == 2:
                    return QVariant(Qt.Unchecked)
                else:
                    return QVariant(Qt.Checked)
            else:
                QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)
        else:
            return QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        # works with changing value, but not saving
        print("-> ImportSqlModel.setData",index,value,role)
        print("   value:", value)
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            print("   = Qt.Editrole")
            QVariant(value)
            print("   Update table")
            self.select()
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet and role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            print("   checkbox changed!")
            if value == Qt.Checked:
                print("   Qt.Checked")
                return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, 2 , Qt.EditRole)
            else:
                print("   not Qt.Checked")
                return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, 0 , Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        print("-> ImportSqlModel.flags")
        print("   index.isValid()",index.isValid())
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            return Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable  | Qt.ItemIsEnabled #  | Qt.ItemIsSelectable  | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        elif index.column() in self.readOnlySet:
            return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        else:
            return QSqlTableModel.flags(self, index)
        print("<- ImportSqlModel.flags")


#######################################################################################################################
#                                               D E M O F U N C T I O N
#######################################################################################################################

def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('memory')
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
                             qApp.tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                                     "how to build it.\n\n"
                                     "Click Cancel to exit."),
                             QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("CREATE TABLE `typeOfValue` (`ID`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, "\
    "`name` TEXT NOT NULL,  `unit`  TEXT NOT NULL,`source` TEXT,`import` INTEGER,`importIfZero` INTEGER,"\
    "`visible`  INTEGER);")

    query.exec_('insert into typeOfValue (name, unit, source, import, importIfZero, visible) values '\
                '("Sound", "dB", "live", 0,0,2)')
    query.exec_('insert into typeOfValue (name, unit, source, import, importIfZero, visible) values '\
                '("Flow", "m/min", "live", 0,2,2)')
    query.exec_('insert into typeOfValue (name, unit, source, import, importIfZero, visible) values '\
                '("Vibration", "mm/s", "live", 2,2,2)')
    query.exec_('insert into typeOfValue (name, unit, source, import, importIfZero, visible) values '\
                '("Voltage", "V", "live", 0,0,0)')
    query.exec_('insert into typeOfValue (name, unit, source, import, importIfZero, visible) values '\
                '("Ampere", "A", "live", 2,0,2)')
    return db
#######################################################################################################################
#                                               M A I N
#######################################################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createConnection()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = ImportFilter()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem I was running in, is that I am able to view the table when I use a query to fill it:

```
def setupModel(self):
    print("-> setupModel")
    # SET query
    qry = QSqlQuery(self.gVar.db)
    sql = "SELECT ID, name, unit, source, Import, ImportIfZero, visible FROM typeOfValue"
    qry.prepare(sql)
    qry.exec_(sql)
    self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setQuery(qry)
```

But I found the fault, that this leads to read-only tables. It is described in the manual that it should not be done: See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setQuery)
So I changed to `.setTable("typeOfValue")` # = Tablename

```
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model = ImportSqlTableModel(self.gVar.db)
        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setTable("typeOfValue")
   self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)

        self.tableView_typeOfValues_Model.select()
```

But now I have an empty view and if I call `self.lastError().text()` I got the message that the table will not be found because `self.database().tables()` (called inside the model) brings an empty list. That means to me, that the database is not initialized correctly, but `self.database()` brings 
*PyQt5.QtSql.QSqlDatabase object at 0x042C4D30* as result.

Please, can someone give me the hint to correct subclassing QSqlTableModel. Thanks!

Comment: Why add one more column to your table?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe I didn't explain clearly. There are 7 column and column 4,5,6 are boolean and will be filled with 0 or 2. One typo in the example, I'll replace it.

Comment: this code: `def columnCount(self, index):
        count = QSqlTableModel.columnCount(self, index)
        return count+1`, is telling the view that it has a new column

Comment: ok, you're right. Thats from a trial. But unfortunaly not the source of my fault.

Comment: I see that you are passing a parameter to the model as the following code shows: ImportSqlTableModel(self.gVar.db), but in your constructor is not indicating that you need parameters. For me that should generate an error that would make the window not show.

Comment: You can show me the structure of the table of the database, that is, what type is each field of the table.

Comment: Table:
CREATE TABLE `typeOfValue` (
 `ID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
 `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
 `unit` TEXT NOT NULL,
 `source` TEXT,
 `import` INTEGER,
 `importIfZero` INTEGER,
 `visible` INTEGER
);
If I don't use the parameter *self.gVar.db* is the same behavior. What's confusing is the following output: 
   ImportSqlTableModel self.db       : <PyQt5.QtSql.QSqlDatabase object at 0x043F3D30>

   ImportSqlTableModel self.Table    : typeOfValue
   ImportSqlTableModel self.rowCount : 0
   ImportSqlTableModel self.lastEror :  Unable to find table typeOfValue

Comment: I can see the tableview with the data, but I can not change the status of the checkboxes, can you see the table? What database are you using?

Comment: I've seen that the call `self.database()` inside the model brings another QSqlDatabase object (QSqlDatabase object at 0x042D4CF0) as the call from outside `ImportSqlTableModel.database()` (QSqlDatabase object at 0x042D4D30). So the database is not set correctly in my opinion.

Comment: That is not correct in PyQt, it usually happens many times due to efficiency issues. You can show a picture of what you get in addition to the connection to your database. Also you have not answered my question. What database do you use: sqlite, mysql, ...?

Comment: It's a SQLITE. What did you do? I thought that the source of the problem with the changes in the checkboxes was the query instead table. This I didn't check already. Can you change fields?

Comment: My only problem is the change of the checkbox, I'm seeing why it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch. What do you mean with picture. The window?

Comment: Yes, and put all the code that reproduces the window, I need you to provide a [mcve]

Comment: That will take while, give me some minutes.

Comment: Check my answer, in the following link I joined my code with yours to already work correctly: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/7f03eb1ef1f9577cdcf988e569eb6f65

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the Qt.ItemIsEditable flag that is not enabled for the Boolean type column, this is necessary in the instruction:

```
if index.column() in self.booleanSet and role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
    print("   checkbox changed!")
    if value == Qt.Checked:
        print("   Qt.Checked")
        return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, 2 , Qt.EditRole)
    else:
        print("   not Qt.Checked")
        return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, 0 , Qt.EditRole)
```

since it verifies that the field can be edited.

So the solution is to enable this flag, but to avoid that you can write some text we will disable the Editor through a delegate:

```
class ReadOnlyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        lb = QLabel(parent)
        return lb
```

Complete Example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant, Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QLabel, QItemDelegate


class ImportSqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImportSqlTableModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.booleanSet = [4, 5, 6]  # column with checkboxes
        self.readOnlySet = [1]  # columns which must not be changed
        self.setTable("typeOfValue")
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.select()

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        value = super(ImportSqlTableModel, self).data(index)
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                return Qt.Unchecked if value == 2 else Qt.Checked
            else:
                return QVariant()
        return QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                val = 2 if value == Qt.Unchecked else 0
                return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, val, Qt.EditRole)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            return Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        elif index.column() in self.readOnlySet:
            return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        else:
            return QSqlTableModel.flags(self, index)


class ReadOnlyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        lb = QLabel(parent)
        return lb


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("/path/of/your_database.db")
    if not db.open():
        sys.exit(-1)
    model = ImportSqlTableModel()
    w = QTableView()
    w.setModel(model)
    for col in model.booleanSet:
        w.setItemDelegateForColumn(col, ReadOnlyDelegate(w))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still searching for the fault of mine, the database issue I didn't find, but the Delegate is what I definetly not did thought about.

Answer (score 0):

The fault regarding the different `QSqlDatabase object`'s was in the call of the subclassed `QSqlTableModel`. It must be `assignedModel = YourSubclassedTableModel(db=your_open_database_object)` if the source is a physical db. If the database is in memory `db.setDatabaseName(':memory:')` then this db is the default db and will be used inside the model. The docs don't mention that. In the Qt manual you will find:

> QSqlTableModel::QSqlTableModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
>   Creates an empty QSqlTableModel and sets the parent to parent and the database connection to db. If db is not valid, the default database connection will be used.

Comment: memory is `:memory:`

Comment: you're right, but the example was working without `:` as well. I'ver corrected the answer.